# copy character from the string in c#

Tags: c#, string

Is there any way available to give start and ending value to the string and string copy all that values in c#
e.g

```
My name is testing.

Now i want to copy 'name is'
```

from the string how i can achieve. I don't have any specific length of the string, It could be increase and decrease.

Comment: what condition do you have it was unclear

Comment: Take a look at SubString and IndexOf functions in C#

Comment: Can you provide some more details or requirements ?

Comment: as i mention in my example want to copy specific length of string.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. `String.Substring` should give you a substring for whatever length you specify.

Comment: @torrentialcoding as when using substring method we need to mention start and end length, Which is unknow

Comment: @rizwanShahid Seth's answer below should work. Try it out.

Comment: Don't know but it could very well be as `string1.Contains("name is")` and you return `"name is"`, so do you really know the string as in **name is**, your question is not so clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

```
String s1 = "My name is testing.";
String sub = "name is";
int index = s1.IndexOf(sub);
String found = s2.Substring(index, sub.Length);
```

Comment: i think he said he dont know position/length

Comment: @Seth if you are using `name is` as value why not just check it using `Contains`

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not completely sure what you are asking here, but...

> I don't have any specific length of the string

Sure you do.

```
string s = "name is";
int len = s.Length;   // len == 7
```

To concatenate strings you can use the `+` operator.

```
string prefix = "prefix : "
string suffix = "suffix : "
string s = prefix + "name is" + suffix;
int len = s.Length;   // len == 25
```

Comment: s I am already having string not want to concatenate want to copy specific length of character

Comment: @rizwanShahid: Then use `SubString()` and 'IndexOf()`.

Comment: @EdS. if he knows its `name is` why not just use `Contains`

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Honestly, I didn't even know what the question was really, just took a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think I nailed your requirement and the solution. Do let me know if this is what you wanted and if this works!

```
MessageBox.Show(FindStringBetween("My name is farhan.", "My", "is"));

public string FindStringBetween(string SourceString, string StartString, string EndString)
{

    int StartSelection = StartString.Length;
    int EndSelection = SourceString.IndexOf(EndString)+EndString.Length;

    return (SourceString.Substring(StartSelection).Substring(0, EndSelection-StartSelection));
}
```